# Anvil tutorial. Subdivisions Surfice modifier creates a face where it should be a hole

Tags: subdivision-surface

I wanted to make an anvil with a tutorial. But as I added the subsurf Modifier it started looking weird. I wanted to make a"Hole" but it fills it up. How can i get it right?[image]

Comment: you need to put edge loops on the bottom so it understands that it's not supposed to be filled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the bottom of the mesh i know it sounds weird but that's what fixed it for me I'm following the same tutorial he shows you how to fix the bottom at the end of the video

Answer (score 0):

The marked edge (see green arrow) causes the problem, since it has influence on the subsurface modifier:
[image: See the green marked edge]

If you delete it, it will solve your problem.